# getting acpi warnings/errors and vgaarb errors. Running Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Z50-70.

Tags: acpi, vga, firmware

Following are the errors or warning that I am getting. I am a complete novice at Linux, so don't have much knowledge of what is going on. Please let me know, if I am required to post the output of some other commands to further present my problem.

**$dmesg | grep ACPI**

```
[    0.181190] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.391298] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    1.391750] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[    1.391755] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[    1.391761] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP.DD02._BCL] (Node ffff88043e8fd000), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[   14.229515] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.229554] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.229572] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.229601] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.229619] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.229654] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.229671] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.243881] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   14.712158] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   20.119724] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878664] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878699] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878719] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878747] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878765] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878800] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.878819] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   31.880983] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
```

**$dmesg | grep "vgaarb"**

```
[    0.276882] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[    0.276884] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.276888] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.276889] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[   31.835392] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   35.364796] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
```

PS: I couldn't add vgaarb as the tag because of my reputation here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/842134/6969 (can unfortunately not close it yet, lacking votes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ACPI Warning Argument #4 type mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842134/acpi-warning-argument-4-type-mismatch)